# VB Setting a label control per character in a word

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB project.  The step says: Set the label control for each character in the word.

The "word" is from a dataset.  Any suggestions on how I can go about this?  It is a hangman game project.

Comment: Read the word into a String variable, loop thru each char in the string and create label control for each char from the loop

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
  Public Sub CreateLabelForEachChar(ByVal aWord As String)
    Dim charArr() As Char = aWord.ToCharArray
    Dim labelCount As Integer
    For Each character In charArr
        Dim aLabel As New Label
        aLabel.Name = "label" & labelCount.ToString
        aLabel.Text = character
        aLabel.Location = New Point(x, y) 'figure out where you wan to put your label
        Me.Controls.Add(aLabel)
        labelCount += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Given this is a hangman game, might be useful to set `aLabel.Tag` to be equal to the character and have `aLabel.Text` be a placeholder character (such as an underscore)